# Spring boot @RequestBody returns null and Could not find acceptable representation

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I created a basic controller for managing documents :

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/documents")
public class DocumentController {

    @Autowired
    private DocumentService documentService;

    @PostMapping(
        consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE },
        produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }
    )
    public DocumentRest getDocumentSigned(@RequestBody DocumentToSignRestRequest  documentToSignRestRequest) throws Exception {

        DocumentDto documentDto = new ModelMapper().map(documentToSignRestRequest, DocumentDto.class);
        DocumentDto signedDocument = documentService.signDocument(documentDto);
        return new ModelMapper().map(signedDocument, DocumentRest.class);
    }
```

}

The document DTO contains fields which are present in DocumentRest POJO and others that are present in DocumentToSignRestRequest.

Actually my service Implementation is the most basic :

```
@Override
public DocumentDto signDocument(DocumentDto document) {
    return document;
}
```

it should return the JSON I send. And I should display the same JSON that i've sent at the end.

I meet 2 issues while using postman : 
the documentToSignRestRequest values are null. And the return I get is the following : "status":406,"error":"Not Acceptable","message":"Could not find acceptable representation. My Json is correctly formatted I think :

```
{
    "obj1": {
        "key1": "val1",
        "key2": "val2",
        "key3": "val3",
        "key4": "val4"
       },
    "obj2": {
        "key1": "val1",
        "key2": "val2",
        "key3": "val3",
        "key4": "val4"
       },
     "key": "value,
     "arr": [
        "whatever"
       ],
    "key": "value"
}
```

Comment: Could you confirm which version of SpringBoot you are using?

Comment: Actually the latest

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the 406 error, i just forgot to define what return i was expected : 
Accept : application/json
I also noticed that I had issues with some constructors. I was used to use lombok and @AllConstructorArgs but it doesn't seem the most appropriate for this.

I solved it by adding a constructor with no params that was able to set the values with the getters.

```
public MyConstructor() {
    this.param1= getParam1();
    this.param2= getParam2();
}
```